# Firebase Remote Config - Real time updation issue

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-remote-config

Our application utilizes Firebase Remote Config to modify its behavior dynamically. We have defined remote config parameters in the Firebase Remote Config dashboard.

To fetch and activate the latest values in a single call, we employ the `fetchAndActivate()` method, which retrieves values from the Remote Config backend and makes them available to the app.

Additionally, we have implemented real-time updates by utilizing the `addOnConfigUpdateListener()` method in our app. This enables us to listen for updates and automatically fetch any new parameter values.

We have implemented the `onUpdate()` callback to activate the updated configuration.
However, we have encountered an issue where the updated values are not being reflected in the app using both the `fetchAndActivate()` method and the real-time update listener.

To troubleshoot the issue, we have performed tests in both our development and production environments. In the development environment, we have set the `minimumFetchIntervalInSeconds` to 0, allowing the app to fetch values from the server every time `fetchAndActivate()` is called. In the production environment, we have set it to 21600 seconds to reduce the frequency of network requests.

Despite these steps, we have not been able to receive the updated values in either case.

Despite updating the libraries to the latest versions, we are still encountering the same issue. The libraries currently in use are:

```
'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.3.6'
'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.2.1'
'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:21.3.0'
```

However, even after updating these libraries, the problem persists. Kindly request guidance on any additional steps we should take to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is any error logged in `onError(error: FirebaseRemoteConfigException)` callback? Also note that the realtime connection only works when the app is in foreground & the api needs to be enabled from `Google Cloud Console`, See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/get-started?platform=android#add-real-time-listener.